# Matlab function to compute average neighbor degree

Tags: matlab, graph, mean, degrees, neighbours

I tried searching a function for matlab that gives the **average neighbor degree** of a graph.

There is a function for the same in python in network-X package. So i was wondering if there's a similar function in matlab.

*************Edit******************

I cannot convert it to an adjacency matrix.. this will occupy too much of space actually.

What i have is the following edge list(Actually this is just a test matrix.. the actual one is pretty large ) as in there's an edge between node 2 to node 1 and so on.. and yes this is an un-directed graph

2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
1   2
3   2
4   2
1   3
2   3
5   3
1   4
2   4
5   4
1   5
3   5
4   5

Now, what i need is a function that will compute the average neighbor degree(mean neighbor degree) for this graph.

Comment: How are you representing the graph? As an adjacency matrix or adjacency list? You have provided very little information here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even for large edge list, you can use Matlab to create an adjacency matrix that fits into memory using [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix:

```
el = [2 1; 3 1; ... ]; %// edge list, I put only a tiny sample here...
n = max( el(:) ); %// number of nodes in the graph
A = sparse( el(:,1), el(:,2), 1, n, n ); % //sparse adjacency matrix
```

The neighbor degree of each node is the number of neighbors

```
nd = sum( A, 2 ); %// degree of each node
```

To compute the average neighbor degree, one can construct another sparse matrix with the neighbor degree stored in each entry

```
ndM = sparse( el(:,1), el(:,2), nd( el(:,2) ), n, n );
```

The average neighbor degree can now be computed from the new matrix

```
av = full( sum( ndM, 2 ) ./ nd );
```

Comment: @Shai Actually, i could get the mean degree of the network. What i wanted to find is the mean degree neighbor of the network. Sorry, but it still doesn't answer my query .

Comment: @Shai I tried running this in the above matrix , but right after i execute ndM i am getting this error "Error using sparse
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.". DO you happen to know the bug?

Comment: @Shai The average neighbour degree of the graph in the matrix example i had given it should come around to be 3.23(it should be a 1X1 vector). But, using your code the solution i am getting is a NX1 matrix.
( the mean neighbor degree(mnd) is equal to the 1/n(mnd of vertex 1+ mnd of vertex 2+...mnd of verex n) )

Comment: according to [this doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.assortativity.average_neighbor_degree.html#networkx.algorithms.assortativity.average_neighbor_degree) mnd should be an n-vector and not a scalar. Why do you expect to get a 1x1 scalar?

Comment: @Shai okay i meant the average of the sum of all such mnd.

But, even so, with that 16 x 2 example matrix above, the mnd vector i should be getting is [3;3.33;3.33;3.33;3.33](found this my manual computation, which is correct), however after using your code, the output i am getting is [2.4;2;2;2;2].

Comment: Wonderful :) It so works!
I couldn't figure out ndM = sparse( el(:,1), el(:,2), nd( el(:,2) ), n, n ); and av = full( sum( ndM, 2 ) ./ nd ); Could you point me to the resource?

Comment: @BoyLittUp I suggest that you look at `full(ndM)` and `full(nd)` computed for the small toy example, this should be quite clear.

Comment: @Shai in the code, ndM = sparse( el(:,1), el(:,2), nd( el(:,2) ), n, n ); 
I have doubt in the code fragment "nd( el(:,2)" . I understand that this value corresponds to the vector el(:,1) and el(:,2). Could you please point out what exactly does nd( el(:,2) does?

Comment: @BoyLittUp `nd( el(:,2) )` creates a vector with the degree (`nd`) of all the neighboring nodes (stored in `el(:,2)`).