# functionality of a Matlab function

Tags: matlab

This question is related to my previous one [Matlab function to compute average neighbor degree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707419/matlab-function-to-compute-average-neighbor-degree?noredirect=1#comment40184255_25707419)

```
el = [2 1; 3 1;4 1;5 1;1 2 ]; %// edge list, I put only a tiny sample here...
n = max( el(:) ); %// number of nodes in the graph
A = sparse( el(:,1), el(:,2), 1, n, n ); % //sparse adjacency matrix
The neighbor degree of each node is the number of neighbors

nd = sum( A, 2 ); %// degree of each node
```

To compute the average neighbor degree, one can construct another sparse matrix with the neighbor degree stored in each entry

***`ndM = sparse( el(:,1), el(:,2), nd( el(:,2) ), n, n );`***

In the above sparse matrix, i understand the functionality of it. However, i don't understand the output thrown by ***nd( el(:,2)***

Could you please point me to the resource?

Answer (score 1):

There is no resource to point to.  This was code customized for your particular application.  BTW, you didn't complete the entire story.  To compute the average degree per node, you need to do:

```
av = full( sum( ndM, 2 ) ./ nd );
```

In any case, `el` is your edge list, where the first column denotes the source node, and the second column is the ending node.  `nd` denotes the degree of each node.  Therefore, by doing:

```
nd(el(:,2))
```

Therefore, you are now creating a new graph where for each pair of nodes, this will contain the degree of the ending node in the edge list, which is what you're supposed to do.

Comment: Actually, i was having a doubt in a particular piece of code i was not familiar with. I have received the answer to my doubt and i am posting it here :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I received the answer in the previous post , `as nd( el(:,2) )` creates a vector with the degree `(nd)` of all the neighboring nodes (stored in `el(:,2))`
That is the solution to my question above given by @Shai in this post [Matlab expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707419/matlab-function-to-compute-average-neighbor-degree/25707621?noredirect=1#comment40410506_25707621)